# Programmatically get field values of fields added to custom entity

Tags: entities

I created a custom entity in Drupal 8, and I added base fields.

I add the getter/setter functions to my entity definition file.
They return `NULL` when called from a preprocess function. (I'm trying to add some variables for the Twig template.)

Why would this be?  I'm using the following code.

```
public function getProjectId() {
    return $this->get('project_id')->value;
}
```

*project_id* is en entity reference field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column for an entity reference field is `target_id`, so you should just need to replace the getter with:

```
public function getProjectId() { 
    return $this->get('project_id')->target_id; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, belatedly showing appreciation.  :)